# Video recorded using MediaRecorder Web API comes with audio sped up

Tags: web, audio, sample, mediarecorder, mediastream

I've been using the MediaRecorder Web API to record a MediaStream obtained using getUserMedia() to record video + audio coming from a webcam + microphone.

[getUserMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia) is not called with specific constraints other than `video = true` and `audio = true`.

[MediaRecorder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder/MediaRecorder) is instantiated with `audioBitsPerSecond` set to `128000` and `videoBitsPerSecond` set to `1024000`.

Most of the time, (I'd say 99% of the time), this setup works and video and audio are recorded in sync and with reasonable quality.

However, I am seeing that some videos, even though they've been properly recorded, come up with audio that seems to be crazily sped up and very low quality. Video playback is fine.

Could this be an issue with the audio sample rate? Note that I am not specifying any [sample rate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaTrackConstraints/sampleRate) constraint when calling `getUserMedia`.

Reproducing this issue on my device has been challenging, making it difficult to debug.

I would greatly appreciate insights from anyone who has experienced and addressed this problem.

I've tried manually setting a sample rate constraint of 48000 when calling `getUserMedia`, but still some videos came up with audio sped up.

I've also tried the `AudioContext` API, setting the sample rate to 48000. No luck.